# Why Continuous function does not map bounded set to bounded set?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, cauchy-sequences, uniform-continuity

I know that any uniformly continuous is fine with it with the particular proof of this theorem I have found.

> **Suppose that f is uniformly continuous on a bounded set S. Prove that f is bounded on S.**

The proof goes like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D45O.jpg). (I can’t format it properly, so I decided to use the picture instead.)
It was all about Cauchy’s Sequence being bounded and contradiction.

My question is :

> Why can’t I just replace the word “**Cauchy’s sequence**” with “**Convergent sequence**” so that I don’t need the function to be uniformly continuous but only regular continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the sequence may not converge to a point of $S$. If $(x_n) \subset S$ and $x _n \to x$ then we can say $x_n-x_m \to 0$ and use uniform continuity to conclude that $f(x_n)-f(x_m) \to 0 $ but continuity can be used only if the limit $x$ is in side $S$.

For example consider the function $\frac  1 x$ on $(0,1)$. The sequence you get from Bolzano-Weistrass Theorem may be $(\frac  1 n)$. Since $f$ is not even defined at $0$ (which is the limit of $\frac  1 n$) we cannot use continuity of $f$.